# Customizing emacs like pycharm IDE

Tags: python, emacs, ide, pycharm, twisted

I am newbie to Emacs. I mostly work in python (specifically twisted) & trying to configure it more like Pycharm IDE. I installed package `elpy`. But still it doesn't work well in case of auto completion. Also it shows all errors in red color either they are errors or warnings. I tweaked pyflakes to show only specific errors ( instead of showing all errors mentioned in PEP8 specifications). But I am trying to make it more like Pycharm.

Has anybody greater luck with this ? Why pycharm is so good in case of autocompletion and finding definitions/sources of functions/classes ? Also  Can we configure virtualenv in emacs ?

Any suggestions/resources/ideas will be welcome.

Comment: upvoted just cause I think pycharm is the best thing since sliced bread ... that said this question is OT so it will likely get closed .... (but I would love to hear a great answer before it closes;P)

Comment: @JoranBeasley thanks

Answer (score 3):

I am a newbie myself, but I did have more luck with `spacemacs`, thanks to the community behind it!. And hopefully this is can be useful for those never used emacs before as well. I had hard time installing so I will make the guide very detail.
I'll be updating this if I find any more package to improve the experience
Read more at github `spacemacs` (Google `spacemacs refactor python code`)

**Final Result Should Have** (Check the image at the end):

- Auto-complete (`C-M-i`)
- Line number (`M-x linum-mode`)
- Python Virtual Environment (`M-x pyvenv-workon`)
- Syntax-checking (`M-x flycheck-mode`)

  - Warning is orange
  - Error is red
- Show Doc of that function/class (`M-?`)

**Table of Content**:

- *Note*
- *Optional Stuff*
- *Prerequisites for Installing Spacemacs*
- *Installation of Spacemacs*
- *Prerequisites for Installing Python Layer*

  - Skip to here to if you already installed spacemacs
- *Installation of Python Layer*
- *Testing Python Layer*
- *Final Note*
- *Summary*

**Note**:

- `commandline`(Windows) and `Terminal`(Linux) as `Terminal`
- `M-x` is to hold alt-key and x-key together

**Optional Stuff**:

- Some knowledge on Vim style key-binding*
- Patience reading through a lot text
- Courage to start from scratch

**Prerequisites for Installing Spacemacs**:

1. Install `Emacs` (Version >= 24.5)
2. Install `Git`

**Installation of Spacemacs**:

1. Start Emacs and close it.
2. Go rename (if any) `.emacs.d` folder to `.emacs.d.bak`.

   - Windows: Should be in `%appdata%`
   - Linux: Should be in Home directory (Might be hidden)
3. Open `Spacemacs` website, click on `install` Copy the link provided.
4. Open up `terminal`, paste the link, press `enter`
5. Wait for the operation to finish
6. Open up `emacs`

*By now you should see:
[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41yU6.png)*

7. Follow the Dotfile-wizard-installer

   - Note: that I use `vim`**, `standard` (Spacemacs), `heavy and full-feature` (Helm)
8. Get a cup of `tea` of your choice while spacemacs install some packages

   - Note: If any package fails to install, restart emacs and it should attempt to reinstall the failed packages.
9. Close `emacs`

**Prerequisites for Installing Python Layer**:

1. Python Virtual Environment

**Installation of Python Layer**:

1. Open `emacs`
2. `M-x find-file` and open a python file
3. There will be a prompt to install python layer, accept the offer
4. Get some cookie while it get packages for python layer
5. Close `emacs`
6. Open dotspacemacs file (`.spacemacs`) in any text editor
7. Go to `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` and:

   - Uncomment `auto-completion`, `spell-checking` and `syntax-checking`
   - Uncomment mean remove `;;` in front
8. Go to `dotspacemacs-additional-packages` and add the following between the brackets

   - `flycheck-pyflakes`
   - Pyflakes is for error checking
9. In `terminal`, run `pip install pyflakes`, in virtual environment of your choice
10. Open `emacs` and with for it to install some stuff

**Testing Python Layer**:

1. `M-x pyvenv-workon` and choose your prefered environment
2. `M-x find-file` and open a python file and make some errors
3. `M-x linum-mode` to show line number
4. Make a function

   - `def asdf4ninja(): pass`
5. Type partial function in like `asdf4`
6. It should autocomplete for you, otherwise auto-complete with anaconda `C-M-i`

   - `C-M-i` is hold `Ctrl`, `Alt` and character `i`
7. In the same file, `import hashlib`
8. Type in the next line `hashlib.` (Note the dot `.`)

*You should see: [Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StjAX.png)*

*Note: The error checking and bottom right `py3.4` is the virtual environment I am using*

**Final Note**:

- `M-?` to show documentation
- You will need to manually

  - `M-x pyvenv-workon` to choose environment on start
  - `M-x linum-mode` to enable lines
- Because I don't know how to make layers to automatically enable them

**Summary**:

- `C-M-i` to auto-complete
- `M-?` to show documentation
- place the cursor in the open bracket `()` to see the function signature
- Read more at `spacemacs`
- Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more thing in your list

Automatic save - `(add-hook 'focus-out-hook 'save-buffer)`

In case, your emacs slows down try
  `(global-hl-line-mode -1)` in `dotspacemacs/user-config`